# Echoing to the screen using AJAX PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I'm trying to write a short ajax code to echo the word 'hello' to the screen, but so far I'm not having any luck. If anyone know what I'm doing wrong, please correct me, and let me know. Thank you.

> test6.html

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type = "text/javascript"> 

function myAjax() {
      $.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           url: 'testing.php',
           data:{action:'call_this'},
           error: function(xhr,status,error){alert(error);},
           success:function(html) {
             alert(html);
           }

      });
}

</script>

<a href="#" onclick="myAjax()">echo hello</a>
```

> testing.php

```
<?php

if($_POST['action'] == 'call_this') {
  echo "hello";
}

?>
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/79587/discussion-on-question-by-iscattered-echoing-to-the-screen-using-ajax-php).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I made some little changes to your code, like adding quotes for 'action', and creating a button because `<A HREF` has some issues with click event (buttons don't have those issues), here it is, now it works to me, let me know if it works to you too :

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type = "text/javascript">
function myAjax () {
$.ajax( { type : 'POST',
          data : {'action':'call_this'},
          url  : 'testing.php',
          success: function ( data ) {
            document.getElementById( "my_div" ).innerHTML = data;
          },
          error: function ( xhr ) {
            alert( "error" );
          }
        });
}
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <a href="" onclick="myAjax()">echo hello</a>
    <br/><br/>
    <button onclick="myAjax()">echo hello</button>
    <br/><br/>
    <div id="my_div"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Yes. It works. But I would like to echo 'hello' on the actual page, instead of on a popup. Is that possible? Thank you.

Comment: I want to echo it right after the echo button. Thank you.

Comment: Thank you. One more question? Is there any way that those library could be taken down at all? I just don't want my website to crash suddenly without me even knowing why if they take the library down for some reason.

Comment: yes, you can download it to your directory and add this = <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.10.2.js"></script> . This way you will not depend on the external site, you will have your own copy of jquery.

Comment: It's not likely that Google is going to have any extended periods of downtime any time soon. Using Google instead of your own server will almost definitely produce a faster page load time.

Comment: Where, and how do I download it?

Comment: @mike Do most people just copy from external link? Which method do you use? Sorry, just curious.

Comment: @JoseManuelAbarcaRodríguez Just curious. Do you use from external link, or from your own directory?

Comment: I don't like external links because they may have modified versions of jquery, and I prefer the original version form the original website. And there is always the fear that the external link will be down from one moment to another.

Comment: @iscattered Craig Buckler posted to SitePoint [7 reasons NOT to use a CDN](http://www.sitepoint.com/7-reasons-not-to-use-a-cdn/) and then the following day posted [7 reasons to use a CDN](http://www.sitepoint.com/7-reasons-to-use-a-cdn/). I recommend you go through both of these articles and make a decision for yourself. To answer your question, personally I *do* use CDNs where possible (except when I'm developing locally) because of faster page load times.

Comment: And about Jose's points, if you use Google's CDN you know exactly which version you are getting and it is always unmodified. I would say it is far more likely that your own site gets hacked and someone modifies the jQuery script than Google's servers getting hacked.

Comment: CDN means [Content Delivery Network](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_delivery_network). If you use googleapis.com that is Google's CDN for those scripts.

Answer (score 2):

You have two problems. First, you have a syntax error. You need a comma after `error`:

```
function myAjax() {
      $.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           url: 'testing.php',
           data:{action:'call_this'},
           error: function(xhr,status,error){alert(error);} /* this comma --> */ , 
           success:function(html) {
             alert(html);
           }

      });
}
```

Second, since you are using an anchor (`<a>`) tag, when you click on the tag it follows the link. You have to prevent that from happening. You can:

- Not use an `<a>` tag
- Put a `href` to something like `#` or `javascript:void(0)`
- Make the function it calls return `false`
- Use [event.preventDefault](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault)

See it on <kbd>[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/23r4yL2f/)</kbd>

**Edit:**

On a side note, you may prefer to just use JavaScript to bind the event handler. This way you get a further separation of JS and HTML, which is typically preferred. Something like this should work:

```
$("#sendAjax").click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: '/echo/html/',
        data:{html:'call_this'},
        error: function(xhr,status,error){alert(error);},
        success:function(html) {
            console.log(html);
            $("#result").text(html);
        }
    });
});
```

Then in your HTML you don't need the `onclick` handler:

```
<a href="#" id="sendAjax">echo hello</a>
```

See it on <kbd>[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/23r4yL2f/3/)</kbd>

Comment: I just added the comma, and updated the codes above. It's still not working.

Comment: Your JSFiddle isn't showing a working ajax query - [here's](https://jsfiddle.net/4nnf3bL3/) a working example. Granted it's simulating the response, but it's a proof of concept!

Comment: @Paul Whether the ajax query accesses a valid URL or not is irrelevant. The function was not even getting called at all.

Comment: Can you give me an example of what you mean when you said put a href to #? If it's not too much trouble, can you update you codes so it include that please? Thank you. If you do, I'll test it out.

Comment: @iscattered The jsfiddle in my answer uses `<a href="#">`

Comment: @Mike It works! Is there a way to output it on the actual page instead of a popup? Thank you.

Comment: @iscattered Sure, in the success function do whatever you want. To put the result into an element on the page, you can use jquery: `$("#yourElem").html(html);` where `yourElem` is the id of the element you want to use to put the result.

Comment: @Mike between yours and jose's answer, I don't know whose to accept. Both of your answers are excellent.